# How to setup ExpressJS with gulp to auto-reload (gulp-live-server)

Tags: node.js, express, gulp

I have a simple ***express 4.x*** test application. I know you can use ***gulp*** to benefit from auto-reloading, so after changing any content on the server, it will automatically restart.

I managed to setup the handlebars template engine with express.

**My file system is very simple:**

- app/main.js -> is the server
- app/gulp.js -> is the gulp file
- app/views/*.hbs -> contains my *handlebars* files
- app/views/layouts/*.hbs -> contains my *handlebars* layout files

I am using the [gulp-live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-live-server) and I have a feeling I am missing something (only watched a couple of tutorials to find out what gulp is)

**app/gulp.js - 2nd example from the [gulp-live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-live-server)**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gls  = require('gulp-live-server');

gulp.task('serve', function() {
    //1. run your script as a server 
    var server = gls.new('main.js');
    server.start();

    //2. run script with cwd args, e.g. the harmony flag 
    var server = gls.new(['--harmony', 'main.js']);
    //this will achieve `node --harmony main.js` 
    //you can access cwd args in `main.js` via `process.argv` 
    server.start();

    //use gulp.watch to trigger server actions(notify, start or stop) 
    gulp.watch(['views/*.hbs', 'static/views/layouts.hbs'], function (file) {
      server.notify.apply(server, [file]);
    });
    gulp.watch('main.js', server.start.bind(server)); //restart my server 

    // Note: try wrapping in a function if getting an error like `TypeError: Bad argument at TypeError (native) at ChildProcess.spawn` 
    gulp.watch('main.js', function() {
      server.start.bind(server)()
    });
});
```

**app/main.js**

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var hbs = require( 'express-handlebars' );

var app = express();

app.engine( 'hbs', 
            hbs( { extname: '.hbs', 
                    defaultLayout: 'layout',
                    layoutsDir: __dirname + "/views/layouts/" } ) );
app.set( 'view engine', 'hbs' );

app.get( "/", function( req, res ) {
    res.render( "index.hbs", {title: "World"} );
} );

app.use( '/public', express.static( 'public' ) );

var port = Number( process.env.PORT || 5000 );
app.listen( port );
```

**What I was expecting:**

After running a **node gulp.js serve** the application would start listening on the port 5000 and be restarted anytime the content on views/* would be changed.

**What is actually happening: **

The gulp only starts and finishes execution.

**Configuration specifics:**

[image]

**Potential problem during gulp installation(?):**

Please notice the deprecated **graceful** component..

[image]

I am sure I am missing something terribly obvious :))

Comment: Livereload and server auto restart are two distinct concepts. Take a look on este, how you can define a gulp task that autorestarts your server:
https://github.com/este/este/blob/1aaa863f8330a47c1993b9399667a8251a9b9cea/gulpfile.babel.js#L73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `node gulp.js serve` means you are executing the `app/gulp.js` file you posted above, then this can't work. The `app/gulp.js` file only *defines* your tasks. It doesn't actually *execute* them.

To execute the tasks you need to install the `gulp` command line tool. The easiest way is to just install `gulp` globally:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

You need to make sure that the location where the command line tool is installed (`npm` will log the location) is in your `PATH` environment variable. Just typing `gulp` on the command line will tell you if that is the case.

Next you need to rename your gulpfile from `app/gulp.js` to `app/gulpfile.js` which is where the `gulp` command line tool looks for your task definitions.

Now you can run `gulp serve` from inside the `app/` directory, which should execute the `serve` task defined in `app/gulpfile.js`.

Comment: Thank you. I still have some issues, but this definitely got me on the right track and am accepting the answer (when I resolve the issues I will post the result in the edit section to let future visitors know how to use set up gulp).

Answer (score 1):

you could try to run your code watching tsc...

`npm run tsc -w`

add this script to your package.json